# Set article attribs on-the-fly via JTable

Tags: php, plugin, articles, jtable

I am using a CCK (Seblod) that extends com_content and allows adding complex fields, like PHP code to be run on onBeforeRender event.
I need to change the values of some `attribs` of an article in the article view, specifically set `show_title` to 0 to hide native Joomla title and replace it with a custom field, and I am trying to to that through this php field attached to *before render* event.

I have checked that in this before render context, I cannot access the `$this` object (it gives me the classical error "Using $this when not in object context"), but I can access current article via

```
$article = JTable::getInstance("content");
$article->load($id);
```

where the `$id` is taken from JInput. I have also seen that I can read the `show_title` value in the JSON value retrieved with `$article->attribs`.

But, as a beginner Joomla developer, I cannot find a way to change that value. Just to be clear: I don't want to change it in the DB (for which I have read I should use JTable->store), I need to change it in the before render so that native Joomla title is not displayed.

`$article->attribs->set...` of course does not work since `$article->attribs` is just a string... but also maybe JTable is not the correct way to do that because it maps to the db...

Is it possible to do that in this context (no access to $this)?

Comment: I got rather confused by your first paragraph, in particular "a third party component (that extends com_content) and is executed as a before render". Joomla components don't really "extend" other components, and a "before render" would be a plugin rather than a component. Could you clarify? And is there a particular reason why can you not do this in a content plugin that triggers on onContentPrepare (https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/Content#onContentPrepare) where the article is passed by reference and you can easily change it? That would be the usual way of doing something like this.

Comment: Hi Robbie, I try to explain: I am using a CCK that extends com_content with additional fields. One of these field is a BeforeRender field where the user can write its PHP to do things before the rendering. I am looking for code to write in this field in order to disable showing Joomla title so that another field is shown as h1.
Inside the before render field, $this has no value, I can access JFactory, JDocuments... and didn't find a way so far to change article attribs (that I can access thorugh JTable) to set show_title to 0.
Is it more clear now? Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Nene, that's clearer now. But more difficult to solve! If your code is running when the Joomla system onBeforeRender event is raised, then I think the component (com_content) will have already been run, and its output buffered with ob_start. So you could check by accessing ob_get_contents and seeing what it contains. If your element is there then you could maybe replace it and regenerate the output buffer. Sorry, I can't think of any other possibility for tackling this.

Comment: Welcome to JSE, @rene.  Please add all relevant details (even if responding to a comment) to the question as an edit so that the full story is all in one cohesive location on the page.  Every time your question is edited, it will be bumped to the top of the Active question queue where it will potentially gain renewed attention from volunteers. As an aside, perhaps introduce yourself and tell us about your Joomla "story" by editing your profile.

Comment: @RobbieJackson thanks. Parsing and regenerating all the output buffer seems to me a bit heavy for performance, am I correct? Anyway I tried to write

`var_dump(ob_get_contents())`

and I get a sad

`NULL string(0) "`

BTW, I never used ob_get_contents so now I am going to search around..

Comment: Are you going to tell us which CCK you're using and where are you placing the code? Whatever it is, using `JTable::getInstance()` won't work because it always create a new instance. You'd need to modify the instance used by the extension, if such exists.

Comment: @Nene, sorry I should have checked. The Joomla code must have already done ob_get_contents() and will have flushed the output buffer. It then puts it into the document, so I coded an onBeforeRender plugin and did $document = JFactory::getDocument();  $buffer = $document->getBuffer();  var_dump($buffer); and it showed me the component output. So if you try that and find the same then it rather confirms that the code runs within the system onBeforeRender event, and I think your only option at that stage might be to analyse the getBuffer() output, modify it, and write it back using setBuffer().

Comment: the CCK is Seblod, the field is called beforeRender and accepts PHP to run on the onBeforeRender event. 

@RobbieJackson: getDocument() works and returns

`object(Joomla\CMS\Document\HtmlDocument)#797 (33) { ["_links"]=> array(0) { } ["_custom"]=> array(0) { } ["template"]=> NULL ["baseurl"]=> NULL ["params"]=> NULL ["_file"]=> NULL ["_template":protected]=> string(0) "" ["_template_tags":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_caching":protected]=> NULL ["_html5":"Joomla\CMS\Document\HtmlDocument":private]=> NULL ["title"]=> string(27) "Search item" ....`

`$document->getBuffer()` returns `NULL`..

Comment: Ok, if getBuffer() returns null then it looks as if it's not running at the same time as the Joomla system onBeforeRender event. I suspect it might be a Seblod-specific event. I'm afraid I don't know Seblod at all, and am not able to help.

Comment: thanks @RobbieJackson anyway :)